# CKeditor : Configure plugin through CKeditor's configuration

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I'm looking for any trick to configure my plugin with arguments in CKEditor's configuration. I have to pass some parameters that I can only pass when my view is displayed.

I want something like this (sample with jQuery adapter) :

```
jQuery('textarea.wysiwyg').ckeditor(function(){},{
        'width'             : '640px',
        'resize_maxWidth'   : '640px', 
        'extraPlugins'      : 'my_plugin',
        'toolbar'           : [['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],['Link', 'Unlink','-','MyPlugin'],['Paste','PasteFromWord'],['Source']]
        'my_plugin'         : {
              'param1'      : 'value1',
              'param2'      : 'value2',
        }

});
```

But I have'nt found yet any information about plugin configuration with CKEditor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer to my own question : 
Plugin method init receive editor as argument, editor contain config (which can be called editor.config) so you can access all configuration defined when you have created your ckeditor instance.

With my sample in my first post, you can access configuration in your plugin like this way :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'my_plugin',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        var param1 = editor.config.value1;
    }
}
```

I think that it's not the best way to do because It adds some extra properties to CKEDITOR.config prototype. It could be better to have a property CKEDITOR.config.extraConfig which is a map of properties by plugins.

Comment: Works for me. But you surely meant `editor.config.param1` instead of `editor.config.value1`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the values to the plugin during editor initialization

```
jQuery('textarea.wysiwyg').ckeditor(function(){}, 
{
        config.extraConfig : { 'param1' : 'value1', 'param2' : 'value2' }
});
```

and access the values in the plugin

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'my_plugin',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        var param1 = editor.extraConfig.param1;
        var param2 = editor.extraConfig.param2;
    }
}
```